# Upload File path not shown in field using wp media uploader

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, file-upload

I am using custom `media upload` in my plugin. In my previous `(before 4.0) WordPress` versions its working perfectly. When I upload audio or image file its upload successfully

[image]

and when i click on `"Insert Into Post"` the path of uploaded file shown in the text field.

[image]

But when I upgrade my `WordPress into 4.4.2` and upload any file its upload successfully

[image]

and when I click on "Insert Into Post" the file path of uploaded file not shown in my text field.

[image]

In both WordPress's the code is 100% same.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" size="50" name="mp3" id="mp3" class="upload-url" />
<input id="st_upload_button" class="st_upload_button" type="button" name="upload_button" value="Upload">
```

And here is my Functions.php Code:

```
function pro_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');

    wp_register_script( 'custom-js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )."js/custom.js");
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js' );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'pro_scripts_method');
```

And here is my JS Code:

```
jQuery('.st_upload_button').click(function() {
    targetfield = jQuery(this).prev('.upload-url');
    tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
    return false;
});

window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
    fileurl = jQuery(html).attr('href');
    //alert(fileurl);
    jQuery(targetfield).val(fileurl);
    tb_remove();
}
```

I alert `fileurl` variable but it gives me undefined value. So please help me for fix that problem

Comment: Have you restarted the wamp or xamp sir.

Comment: I am working on my online server

Comment: I have the same problem in last week. My database connection was disconnected and wamp was not working properly. When i restarted it all was working fine then.

Comment: hmmmm but i am not working on local

Comment: bro my issue is not database. because I did'nt see file path when i click on "insert in post" the insertion of post is far far above step

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change that new WordPress made to their media upload is the empty **Link URL** field.

[image]

But if you click `file url` button below that field and then click `Insert Into Post` your code works well :)

So we need a simple way to automatically put the `file url` value in the **Link URL**. I don't know about it whether there is a setting for that in wordpress or not but there is a simple code I wrote in **jQuery** to achieve it and it works really well for me.

What I'm really doing is:

When user hit the `Insert into Post` button. My **jQuery** check the parent of that `Insert into Post` button and find the `file url` value and insert it into **Link URL** field. That's it! Simple right?

```
jQuery('.savesend input[type=submit]').click(function(){  
         var url = jQuery(this).parents('.describe').find('.urlfile').data('link-url');
         var field = jQuery(this).parents('.describe').find('.urlfield');
         field.val(url);
     });
```

So try it out and let me know :)

Answer (score 3):

Why aren't you using [`wp.media`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.media)?

Try with this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    "use strict";

    $('.st_upload_button').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $input_field = $(this).prev();
        var custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: 'Add Audio',
            button: {
                text: 'Add Audio'
            },
            multiple: false
        });
        custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
            var attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            $input_field.val(attachment.url);
        });
        custom_uploader.open();
    });

});
```

This will open the media screen on button click, and put the url to the input field.

Comment: bro now my media up loader not open with your code :'(

Comment: You'll need to modify your code. You don't need `tb_show()`. Be sure to clean the old code before putting the new one in. And watch for any errors in the inspector.

Answer (score 2):

Their is a new version of the wordpress uploader since Wordpress 3.5. Maybe the way you did it is not available in Wordpress 4.0

You could find a basic tutorial here:
http://www.webmaster-source.com/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){


    var custom_uploader;


    $('#upload_image_button').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
        if (custom_uploader) {
            custom_uploader.open();
            return;
        }

        //Extend the wp.media object
        custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: 'Choose Image',
            button: {
                text: 'Choose Image'
            },
            multiple: false
        });

        //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
        custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
            attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            $('#upload_image').val(attachment.url);
        });

        //Open the uploader dialog
        custom_uploader.open();

    });


});
```

```html
<label for="upload_image">
    <input id="upload_image" type="text" size="36" name="ad_image" value="http://" /> 
    <input id="upload_image_button" class="button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
    <br />Enter a URL or upload an image
</label>
```

```html
//This part Should be in function.php (or similar)

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts');

function my_admin_scripts() {
    if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'my_plugin_page') {
        wp_enqueue_media();
        wp_register_script('my-admin-js', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/my-plugin/my-admin.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('my-admin-js');
    }
}
```

Comment: hey @jordane There are two glitches ... if you can fix them ... your answer will working perfectly for me .... sor please fix it

Comment: What do you mean by two glitches ?

Comment: First i can't chose any previous attachment
Second if I upload new file and when i click three times on "choose image" button then it shows in to input field
and third I have 2 upload fields and their buttons with same id and name so i call two times your jquery code with different name and id